# Habilitar extensões no Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Estou usando o *Google App Engine - PHP* com *Laravel 5*, e estou querendo usar a Classe `Intervention/Image`, porém para usá-la eu preciso ativar a extensão `fileinfo` do PHP, mas não sei como fazer isso no Google App Engine.

Criei o *php.ini* na mesma pasta do *app.yaml* mas não funcinou.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Pode postar o trecho do .ini no qual vc adicionou a extensão ?

Answer (score 0):

O Google App Engine não suporta essa extensão ainda.

O que você pode fazer é abrir uma [*issue*](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=php%20extension&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&cells=tiles) e torcer para implementarem.

Talvez incluir um [*package*](https://packagist.org/packages/madslundholmdk/fileinfo) que simule as funções `fileinfo()` possa resolver seu problema.